# SQL select multiple values present in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I have two tables DiagnosisCodes and DiagnosisConditions as shown below. I need to find the members(IDs) who have a combination of Hypertension and Diabetes. The problem here is the DiagnosisCodes are spread across 10 columns. How do I check if the member qualifies for both conditions

**DiagnosisCodes**

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
| ID | Diag1 | Diag2 | Diag3 | ... | Diag10 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
| A  |  2502 |  2593 | NULL  | ... | NULL   |
| B  |  2F93 |  2509 | 2593  | ... | NULL   |
| C  |  C257 |  2509 | C6375 | ... | NULL   |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
```

**DiagnosisConditions**

```
+------+--------------+
| Code |  Condition   |
+------+--------------+
| 2502 | Hypertension |
| 2593 | Diabetes     |
| 2509 | Diabetes     |
| 2F93 | Hypertension |
| 2673 | HeartFailure |
+------+--------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
+---------+
| Members |
+---------+
| A       |
| B       |
+---------+
```

How do I query to check Mulitple values which are present in Multiple columns. Do you suggest to use `EXISTS`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM   diagnosiscodes 
WHERE  ( diag1, diag2...diag10 ) IN (SELECT code 
                                     FROM   diagnosiscondition 
                                     WHERE  condition IN ( 'Hypertension','Diabetes' ) 
                                     )
```

Comment: The columns `Diag1 | Diag2 | Diag3 | ... | Diag10` are all diagnosis....it should be just one column...

Comment: Exactly...and if the person has only 3 conditions, just 3 rows; instead of 3 fields with data and 7 null fields...

Comment: Consider how bad this design would be if they have an 11th condition. You would have to add another column to your table and change every query. This violates 1NF because you have repeating groups. Read more about repeating groups here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: True! This is the raw data given to me, I'm trying to pivot and take out the required information. They have about 25 Diagnosis columns :/ and 300 million records with the same design

Comment: Absolutely agree... this should be vertical data in one column.  Much more flexibility... such as adding a diagnosis date, or marking something "done" or linking to prescription data by foreign key - or checking who has hypertension and diabetes :) or having 11 medical conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select dc.id
from diagnosiscodes dc join
     diagnosiscondistions dcon
     on dcon.code in (dc.diag1, dc.diag2, . . . )
group by id
having sum(case when dcon.condition = 'diabetes' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when dcon.condition = 'Hypertension' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Then, you should fix your data structure.  Having separate columns with the same information distinguished by a number is usually a sign of a poor data structure.  You should have a table, called somethhing like `PatientDiagnoses` with one row per patient and diagnosis.

Comment: Based on Hackerman and your suggestion I Extracted the data into a new table and made a single column called DX like " MemberID | ConditionName | ConditionID | DX "

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way by unpivoting the data

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Diag1),(Diag2),..(Diag10))tc(Diag)
WHERE  Diag IN (SELECT code
                FROM   diagnosiscondition
                WHERE  condition IN ( 'Hypertension', 'Diabetes' ) group by code having count(distinct condition)=2)
```

Comment: I understand the answer, but not the upvotes.  This does not find patients with both conditions.